# Get root node or nodes in adjacency datatable using VB.Net LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable (adjacency table) that has 2 columns Parent, Child 
I am trying to find out the top level nodes (node that has no parent), if I would have done this in SQL it would be similar to this

```
Select distinct Parent from theTable
Where Parent Not IN (Select Child from theTable)

parent/child
1/2
1/3
3/4
4/5
```

top node in this case would be 1

How could I achieve this in using LINQ with datatable in VB.Net?

Something like this non-working suedo:

```
Dim root As DataRow = From p In theTable.Rows
Where p.Parent not in (from c in theTable.Rows select c.Child)
Select r.Parent
```

Thanks!

Comment: The root is the one without parent, not the one without child. Nodes without children are called "leaf" in most cases.

Comment: oh yeah, I messed that up. I updated the post. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When doing linq queries on `DataTable`, you should use `AsEnumerable` to access the rows.  Your query becomes this:

```
(From r In theTable.AsEnumerable
Where Not (
    From c In theTable.AsEnumerable
    Select c.Field(Of Integer)("Child")
).Contains(r.Field(Of Integer)("Parent"))
Select r.Field(Of Integer)("Parent")).Distinct
```